# GAS OAuth won’t allow authorization

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script

I attempt to authorize a GAS script and I get the following message.

> “Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. Please try your request again later.”

[Here is a link to the actual page.](http://www.google.com/sorry/misc/?continue=http://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken)

None of the reasons listed on the explanation page apply.

Has anyone got a solution?

Comment: Did this ever use to work? If it worked at some point, when did it start happening? Is it still happening? Are you using a regular gmail account or is your account part of a Google Apps domain?

Comment: It is an intermittent failure. The system works most of the time. I thought I had isolated the problem down to when I am logged into two computers at the same time on the same network but I experienced a counter example recently. So I have to eliminate that as a cause. I have a regular gmail account.

Comment: I see. Is it still happening? If it is, please also share some code on what services you are trying to "oauth" enable

Comment: My current theory is that the problem is caused intermittently due to a script I own making automated requests, as per mentioned in the link explanation. If anyone wants to post an answer to this question of a reasonable nature or that adds something to the issue, I will be happy to accept the answer and close the question until the problem re-emerges or my theory proves false by counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there may have been a brief issue with the outbound connections you are making with UrlFetchApp. Please stay mindful of the quotas described here

https://script.google.com/dashboard (go to Quotas tab)

And if this happens again please provide any further details you might have.

Comment: For those who might benefit from this... I finally identified the cause and solution to the problem.The cause was the fact that I had automatic scripts running in the background. Apparently, this caused quota and/or TOS issues with Google. The solution was to turn off the automatic scripts.